# Does firebase app data collection need to be declared in Data Safety Form of Play Console?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-console

Google has recently updated its play console Data Safety Form. It requires filling out the data collected and shared by the app. Is the data collected by the firebase or crashlytics is needed to declared in the Data Safety Form?

For example, Firebase Analytics collects user location. Does the location segment of the Data Safety Form should be filled. Google says in its official document that **"check your app’s declared permissions and the APIs that your app uses."**

My app has no such permission declared in the menifest file. Should we still declare it because of Firebase Analytics?

At some place in docs, google says **"Transferring user data that has been fully anonymized so that it can no longer be associated with an individual user"**

Is the Firebase collects crashlytics and analytics anonymously?

My app required no permission and used firebase library for crashlytics, analytics, and push notification. What should I fill in Data Safety Form?

Comment: Good question, I'm also looking for 'the' way to fill in the form when only using firebase analytics and crashlytics. Should be an easy thing for Google todo, because they now how Firebase works and they created this form themselves.

Answer (score 16):

I searched on Google and found [this page on Firebase site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/play-data-disclosure).

[Follow this repo](https://github.com/Privado-Inc/SDK-Privacy-Report/blob/main/Android%20App%20-%20SDK%20Privacy%20Report.csv) while filling the data safety form.

Comment: According to a Google Play Developer email I received, April 2022 is the deadline to have the Data Safety form filled in and approved. In the email was also the following statement: "Without an approved section, your new app submission or app update may be rejected. There may also be additional enforcement actions in the future."

Comment: [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/play-data-disclosure) given by @kumar is having all the details now. for Admob, see [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/play-data-disclosure).

Comment: is there any already prepared data safety CSV? its very dificult to fill the form, i use firebase sdk and sentry sdk in my application.

Comment: If anyone is wondering where the yes/no answers will be useful in Follow this repo link, see steps here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71234298/14784590

Comment: Thanks but what exactly should we specify when using libs like Firebase - is data *Collected* or *Shared* or both?

Answer (score 2):

I created an Android Studio plugin that can detect the SDKs in your app and automatically generate the CSV form. It covers all the SDKs listed in the Google Play SDK index (https://play.google.com/sdks) that provides official guidance on how to fill out the data safety section for the SDK.

For more details (tutorials, demo video, team information), please visit the project website:
http://matcha-ide.github.io/

And it's now released to the JetBrains plugin marketplace. You can simply search "Matcha" (the plugin name) in your IDE and install it:)