# Action Required: Your app is not compliant with Google Play Policies , what is the solution?

Tags: android, app-store, store, playback

[image]

Issue found: Invalid Data safety section
We reviewed your app's Data safety section in Play Console and found discrepancies between it and how the app collects and shares user data. All apps are required to complete an accurate Data safety section that discloses their data collection and sharing practices - this is a requirement even if your app does not collect any user data.

We detected user data transmitted off device that you have not disclosed in your app's Data safety section as user data collected.

Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

> SPLIT_BUNDLE 2: Policy Declaration for Play Safety Label: Device Or Other IDs Data Type - Device Or Other IDs (some common examples may include Advertising ID, Android ID, IMEI, BSSID)**

Comment: Update questionnaire on play store console under App content, add privacy policy. Check this answer if it solve your problem  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50267910/my-app-violates-the-android-advertising-id-policy

Comment: same problem here , is it send for every developers ??

Comment: @amirhesni Yes, I have received a similar message. But the code of problem - SPLIT_BUNDLE 72 instead of 2

Comment: Will this affect the affected app deployment?

Comment: Does any one knows what SPLIT_BUNDLE is?

Comment: @TimWeb this number just after SPLIT_BUNDLE is the build version

Answer (score 279, accepted):

1. Open `Google Play Console`
2. App content
3. Data safety => Manage
4. Overview click next
5. Answer the questions (then next):

   - Does your app collect or share any of the required user data types?
     = yes
   - Is all of the user data collected by your app encrypted in transit?
     = yes
   - Do you provide a way for users to request that their data is deleted?
     = yes
6. go to `Device or other IDs` and check it then `next`
7. check Device or other IDs and manage it
8. answer the questions

   - Is this data collected, shared, or both?
     = Collected
   - Is this data processed ephemerally?
     = yes
   - Is this data required for your app, or can users choose whether it's collected?
     = Users can choose whether this data is collected
   - Why is this user data collected?
     = check `App functionality`
9. then save
10. click next and save and app will review and approved by play store team

Comment: anyone knows how to tackle: Is your app currently certified by an authorized lab, according to the Mobile Application Security Assessment (MASA) framework?

Comment: @Bawantha if your app is security checked by a Google third-party service w.r.t. MASA framework, set is as Yes.
Else just leave No.

Comment: Thanks. Google should hire you to rewrite their own emails and documentation :/

Comment: Q No 8 -> Is this data collected, shared, or both? = Collected . Should we also click 'shared' . My app is a weather app and I don't collect it personally, rather the location is transmitted to a third party app that provides the weather support.

Comment: Just to interject; be sure to just respond to these truthfully and not outright copy the answers he has provided; for example I imagine most devs do nto have a way to delete data and claiming so might get you into big trouble with the GDPR laws in the extremely unlikely event someone would try and follow up your dishonestly with legal reprocussions. Same goes with the other questions- just answer honestly

Comment: What a lifesaver. I don't have any ads or transmit any device ids, but I started getting this rejection error in my last release. I never got this error before.

Comment: Firebase CrashLytics / Other service users, refer here for yes / no questions https://stackoverflow.com/a/69865716/14784590 (Refer the Follow this repo link)

Comment: Note that Step 6 is entirely dependent on what you received from Google Play.

Comment: @user2233706 maybe you still have the AdMob SDK in your App, even if you aren't using it

Comment: First - why `Is this data processed ephemerally? = yes` it's NOT temporary in the memory if it's Admob, so then answer is `NO`. Second - why `App functionality`? You can select `Advertising or marketing`, I don't think app really needs it for its main functions

Comment: If we go with this , Do you provide a way for users to request that their data is deleted? = yes it requests a url. what does content of the link look like?

Comment: For Google SDKs such as firebase crashlytics, there is a table which specifies each https://github.com/Privado-Inc/SDK-Privacy-Report/blob/main/Android%20App%20-%20SDK%20Privacy%20Report.csv

Answer (score 1):

**Only ads user AdMob, Facebook etc. - [Data collected and shared automatically](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/play-data-disclosure)**

1. Open Google Play Console
2. App content
3. Data safety => Manage
4. On Top Right side you see Import from CSV file. Here, simply upload
   the Data-Sefty.csv file ONLY.

**Download Data Safety Form:** https://www.technovimal.in/action-required-your-app-is-not-compliant-with-google-play-policies-what-is-the-solution.html

then save

Click next and save and the app will review and approved by the play store team.

[image: AdMob, Facbook - Data collected and shared automatically]

Comment: I am using facebook ads in my mobile app. Is this 'Data-Sefty.csv' file ok for facebook ads?

Comment: Don't use  Import from CSV file of others accounts

Comment: what if i am not using ads?

Comment: The csv file is not available anymore, where can i get it?

Answer (score -3):

All solution are good but you just try simple  way.

Follow This simple steps :

1. Open Google Play Console
2. App content
3. Data safety => Manage
4. Top Right side you see Import from CSV file.
   Here, simply upload Data-Sefty.csv file ONLY.

Download Data Safety Form : https://drive.google.com/file/d/107ovp_HwPdoo-fE9X97ipoDh1sBkHmV4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Following error shown
You cannot answer PSL_DATA_USAGE_RESPONSES:PSL_NAME:PSL_DATA_USAGE_EPHEMERAL

Comment: Put your own solution, don't copy and paste others solution.