# Your app is not compliant with Google Play Policies SPLIT_BUNDLE 12: Policy Declaration Data Safety Section: Location

Tags: android, location, google-play-console

I have an application where i'm basically getting user location to fetch latitude and longitude and make an http request , my app worked fine on google play until i had to update to sdk 33 , when i uploaded my aab file , they sent a message with the below "Action Required" , the action is about location but i'm not sure what is wrong , if anyone could help Thank you .

[image]

Comment: Its Gonna take a lot of reading .. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10787469?hl=en#zippy= .. Check [These Steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71234298/4168607) .. you will have do same for your Action ..

Comment: Thank you I'm actually reading it , but since i'm using location on user device to get latitue and longitude and create http request to fetch some data which means that upon transit data is not secure , will that cause any issue ?

Comment: No i think . all you gotta do is  provide a disclosure in data safety form of data you are using/collecting in your case location ..  Read the data sharing and data type section  ..  then go to section `Completing the Data safety form in Play Console`..

Comment: Thank you for your help , i have read little bit about it and submitted the form , appreciate your time and effort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most properly this is how you should answer the data safety form:

Precise location:

- Collected?    Yes
- Shared? No
- Processed ephemerally? No (or yes if you do not know who is the user when you process the location
- Required? Yes
- Purposes? App functionality

Comment: Instead of collected , i selected shared and the rest is the same , Thank you mate , but the reason that i'm using location is to append latitude and longitude and request prayer timing from api based on certain location , do you think that would Collected or Shared , my understanding led to me choose Shared .