# How to solve - Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: App Activity Data Type - Apps On Device

Tags: android

My Android app have  "Issue: Google Play Policy Violation"

with additional information:

> Invalid Data safety section
>
> We reviewed your Data safety section and found discrepancies between your disclosure and app behavior. For example, we found the following data types sent off device that were not yet disclosed:
>
> Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: App Activity Data Type - Apps On Device
> APK: 250020801

I can't find in my application any usage of any library that  is asking the phone what other apps are installed

How can I find the reason and resolve it.
My previous apk have no such issue.

Thanks.

i looked at AndroidManifest.xml and not found "QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" or "INSTALL_PACKAGES" permissions

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71199143/action-required-your-app-is-not-compliant-with-google-play-policies-what-is-t

Comment: No, it is no Apps On Device

Comment: You can "resolve" it, by selecting "Installed Apps" in Play Console -> <my app> -> Policy and Programs: App Content -> Actioned | Need Attention -> Data Safety -> Manage -> Data Types -> App Activity -> Installed Apps. For us, we resolved it by not sending the package name of the app that our content was shared to in a tracking request.