# SPLIT_BUNDLE 3: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: , What's the solution?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, playback

Issue found: Invalid Data safety form
We reviewed your app’s Data safety form in Play Console and found discrepancies between it and how the app collects and shares user data. All apps are required to complete an accurate Data safety form that discloses their data collection and sharing practices - this is required even if your app does not collect any user data.

We detected user data transmitted off device that you have not disclosed in your app’s Data safety form as user data collected.

You must ensure that your app’s Data safety section accurately reflects your app’s data collection, sharing, and handling practices. This includes data collected and handled through any third-party libraries or SDKs used in your app. When available, we’ve included details on SDKs that contain code similar to the code in your APK that may be sending user data off device. You can check if your app uses any of these SDKs, but note that this list of SDKs may not be exhaustive. You must review and account for all data collected and shared by your app.

Your app may face additional enforcement actions, if you do not resolve this issue by February 21, 2023.
Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

SPLIT_BUNDLE 3: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Device Or Other IDs Data Type - Device Or Other IDs (some common examples may include Advertising ID, Android ID, IMEI, BSSID, MAC address)

We found an issue in the following area(s):

SPLIT_BUNDLE 3: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Device Or Other IDs Data Type - Device Or Other IDs (some common examples may include Advertising ID, Android ID, IMEI, BSSID, MAC address)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Action Required: Your app is not compliant with Google Play Policies , what is the solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71199143/action-required-your-app-is-not-compliant-with-google-play-policies-what-is-t)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Open Google Play Console
2. App content
3. Data safety => Manage
4. Overview click next
5. Answer the questions (then next):

   - Does your app collect or share any of the required user data types?
     =    yes
   - Is all of the user data collected by your app encrypted in transit? = yes
   - Do you provide a way for users to request that their data is deleted? = yes
6. go to Device or other IDs and check it then next
7. check Device or other IDs and manage it
8. answer the questions:

   - Is this data collected, shared, or both? = Collected
   - Is this data processed ephemerally? = yes
   - Is this data required for your app, or can users choose whether it's collected? = Users can choose whether this data is collected
   - Why is this user data collected? = check App functionality
9. then save
10. click next and save and app will review and approved by play store
    team

I solved my own problem in this way. You also can try this. it should be work if your is:

> SPLIT_BUNDLE 3: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Device Or
> Other IDs Data Type - Device Or Other IDs (some common examples may
> include Advertising ID, Android ID, IMEI, BSSID, MAC address)