# Issue found: Invalid Data safety form google play console error

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

Issue found: Invalid Data safety form
We reviewed your app’s Data safety form in Play Console and found discrepancies between it and how the app collects and shares user data. All apps are required to complete an accurate Data safety form that discloses their data collection and sharing practices - this is required even if your app does not collect any user data.

We detected user data transmitted off device that you have not disclosed in your app’s Data safety form as user data collected.

You must ensure that your app’s Data safety section accurately reflects your app’s data collection, sharing, and handling practices. This includes data collected and handled through any third-party libraries or SDKs used in your app. When available, we’ve included details on SDKs that contain code similar to the code in your APK that may be sending user data off device. You can check if your app uses any of these SDKs, but note that this list of SDKs may not be exhaustive. You must review and account for all data collected and shared by your app.

Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

SPLIT_BUNDLE 25: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Device Or Other IDs Data Type - Device Or Other IDs (some common examples may include Advertising ID, Android ID, IMEI, BSSID, MAC address), Possible SDKs: com.applovin:applovin-sdk
SPLIT_BUNDLE 27: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Device Or Other IDs Data Type - Device Or Other IDs (some common examples may include Advertising ID, Android ID, IMEI, BSSID, MAC address), Possible SDKs: com.applovin:applovin-sdk

I am getting this email from google play console team when i sent my app for review, how to resolve this.

Answer (score 4):

Normally if you are using Admob then most of above data is collected and may be shared.
please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71234298/2828651) one and it should be resolved.