# SPLIT_BUNDLE 2: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Personal Info Data Type - Email Address | any solution for this ? received on 25 Feb 2023

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, imei

[image]
We detected user data transmitted off device that you have not disclosed in your app’s Data safety form as user data collected.

You must ensure that your app’s Data safety section accurately reflects your app’s data collection, sharing, and handling practices. This includes data collected and handled through any third-party libraries or SDKs used in your app. When available, we’ve included details on SDKs that contain code similar to the code in your APK that may be sending user data off device. You can check if your app uses any of these SDKs, but note that this list of SDKs may not be exhaustive. You must review and account for all data collected and shared by your app.

Your app may face additional enforcement actions, if you do not resolve this issue by March 11, 2023.
Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

SPLIT_BUNDLE 2: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Personal Info Data Type - Email Address

Action required: Submit an updated app for review
Here's what to do to help get your app on Google Play:

1. Make sure to read the applicable policies or requirements listed below:
2. Data safety section in Google Play User Data policy
3. Make appropriate changes to your app (if possible), and be sure to address the issue described above. You may also want to check your app's store listing for compliance, if applicable.
4. Double-check that your app is compliant with all other Developer Program Policies.
   If you made changes to your app bundle, store listing, or APK, please sign in to your Play Console and submit the update(s).

**EDIT**

I never collected any type of data nor used any ad framework,

but in one class I used :->

```kotlin
 binding.sendFA.setOnClickListener {
            val feedbackMsg = binding.feedbackMsgFA.text.toString() + "\n" + binding.emailFA.text.toString()
            val subject = binding.topicFA.text.toString()

            val userName = "123456789@gmail.com" //changed
            val pass = "123456789" //changed

            val cm = this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
            if(feedbackMsg.isNotEmpty() && subject.isNotEmpty() && (cm.activeNetworkInfo?.isConnectedOrConnecting == true)){
                Thread{
                    try {
///
//
/
.
}}}
```

is I have to re-update my app and remove this function
OR
I have to change my data safety form.

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Action Required: Your app is not compliant with Google Play Policies , what is the solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71199143/action-required-your-app-is-not-compliant-with-google-play-policies-what-is-t)

Comment: They make arbitrary rules, apply them arbitrarily and don't answer your queries in a logical or understandable way. I have the same problem, Ive emailed them many times that I don't collect user email, and they kept sending back same copy/paste messages. Maybe its time to ditch those app stores.

Comment: I agree, @damdafayton Also, in this case, if we are using any hardcoded email or any editText with `android:inputType="textEmailAddress"`, then we have to specify that we are collecting email addresses.

Comment: I am collecting email address. But its not user's. Hence no need to declare i suppose

Comment: then the workAround is remove android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
and don't use email word in XML and in your code