# App is not compliant with Google Play Policies

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, privacy, google-developers-console

[image]

Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

SPLIT_BUNDLE 3000: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Location Data Type - Precise Location

Can someone help me to remove this issue.

Comment: Have you tried making the changes they requested, and resubmitting it?

Comment: I don't know what to change

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have clicked mostly NO on you Data Safety form. Here is a guide to access the form and make changes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71234298/5525657
In your case find the question about Location and specify if this data is for the functionality of the app or is shared to your servers or third party