# Issue found: Invalid Encryption Declaration on your Data safety form

Tags: android, google-play

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vt5q.png)

Issue found: Invalid Encryption Declaration on your Data safety form We’ve detected discrepancies between how your app collects and shares user data and what was declared in your app’s Data safety form. All apps are required to complete an accurate Data safety form that discloses their data collection and sharing practices - this is required even if your app does not collect any user data.

You have declared that user data is encrypted in transit in your app’s Data safety form and we’ve detected unencrypted network traffic that may carry user data off device.

Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

SPLIT_BUNDLE 2: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: "http://atracking-auto.astrodsp.com"

The libraries I use are:

1. Java-WebSocket - github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket
2. Connect-SDK-Android - github.com/ConnectSDK/Connect-SDK-Android
3. AndroidAsync - github.com/koush/AndroidAsync
4. nv-websocket-client - github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client

I suspect it's coming from the Connect-SDK-Android library. So is there any way to solve this problem completely? I tried searching but still can't find it.
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your app using `http` schema to transfer data, however, in your `App's Data safety` form, you've declared that user's data is encrypted in transit in your app. It is conflict.

The `http` link that Google found is http://atracking-auto.astrodsp.com

You have to:

1. Update the declaration in App's Data safety form to `unencrypted` in transit. Or
2. Update your link to using `https` schema.

Comment: thank you for the answer, however my app used few libraries on github and i don't know which one contains this code.
The libraries I use are:
1. Java-WebSocket - https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket
2. Connect-SDK-Android - https://github.com/ConnectSDK/Connect-SDK-Android
3. AndroidAsync - https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync
4. nv-websocket-client - https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client

I tried searching for http links in there but couldn't find them, can you help me?

Comment: After a while of review and reference, I suspect that it's because the Connect-SDK-Android library already has that activity, because there is "android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"". However, I still can't find that tracking link anywhere

Comment: Sorry to hear that, It's hard to find from the used libraries. You can see the link is redirected to `https` when i clicked. Try to look at the same issue  https://stackoverflow.com/q/71199143/3682565 maybe this help